# Setting Google Maps v2 API key at runtime

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Is it possible to set Google Maps v2 API key at runtime instead of having the same one embedded in the manifest? I don't see anything useful for this purpose in API docs.

Answer (score 1):

From the Google Maps for Android documentation, you need to set your API key in your manifest XML file. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key

It was possible to set the API key thru the MapView constructor in v1 [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView#MapView(android.content.Context, java.lang.String)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView#MapView(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)). But not possible in v2 anymore.